# Входит ли в скомпилированную программу языков C#, VB.NET и F# дополнительная информация?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, безопасность, компилятор, декомпиляция

Меня интересует, что кроме самого кода и необходимых для работы метаданных, входит в программу, и потом может быть декомпилированно тем же Reflector. Например, информация о компании, разработчике, дата сборки и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, туда может войти информация о версии сборки, авторских правах и т п
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/set-assembly-attributes

Если указать соответствующие атрибуты.

Для получения этой информации даже ничего не придется декомпилировать и ее можно будет получить в свойствах файла в резделе подробно.

Comment: То есть, без ведома разработчика туда ничего такого не попадает, так?

Comment: Не уверен, но по идее, да.